# Getting percentage using histogram when used with facetting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame

```
z x y
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 1 a
4 2 a
5 1 b
6 9 b
7 9 b
8 8 b
9 7 b
```

when I do

```
p = ggplot(z,aes(x,group=y)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..,group=y)) +       facet_grid(y ~ .)
p
```

I get the faceted plots, but not with the percentages on the y-axis for each symbol within z$y.

Basically, I want a histogram chart, but with the percentages that show the frequency distribution within each value of z$y i.e. a,b.

In this case, under 'a', 50% is 1 and 50% is 2, and under 'b', 20% is 1, 40% is 9, 20% is 7 and 20% is 8. I want this charted as histograms using faceting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a histogram (there is no density estimation), but a bar chart.

```
d <- data.frame( 
  value = c(1,2,1,2,1,9,9,8),
  group = c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4))
)
# With counts
ggplot(d) + geom_bar(aes(factor(value))) + facet_grid(group ~ .)
# With percentages
ggplot(d) + 
  geom_bar(aes(factor(value), (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent') + 
  facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

**Note**: In more recent versions of **ggplot2** we would use `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())` instead, and make sure to load the **scales** package.

Comment: @lajkssfjd - Glad Vincent was able to help you. To let others know that his answer solved your problem you can click on the check mark to its left. (To mark his answer as a good one, you can also, if you'd like, give it an upvote.) Thanks!

Comment: The percentages are scaled for the whole data set rather than the facet subsets, ie in `a`, the values are both 25% rather than 50%.